# RTL Viewer Command line

Tags: modelsim, intel-fpga, quartus

What is the command to run Alter Quartus RTL Viewer, or ModelSim RTL from the Command line under Windows?

I tired the following command, however RTL Viewer window does not appear

```
quartus_rpp t -c t --netlist_type=sgate
```

where `t` is my project's name and my top level design entity.

Comment: Not related to your question, but what is `sgate`? I saw it some time ago.

Comment: @Paebbels gate level netlist.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all quartus binaries are in path and following your convention, `t` is top module name and top design entity:

1. First run analysis and synthesis step.

```bash
quartus_map t -l /RTL/FILE/DIRECTORY
```

2. Generate the netlist

```bash
quartus_npp t --netlist_type=sgate
```

3. Open the netlist via gui

```bash
gnui t
```

All of the output files will be placed in the directory where you run the commands.

- Where did I found those steps?

As you know there is no documentation for both `gnui` and `quartus_npp`. So, the only way to get some information is to read someone's code who use these binaries.
There are bunch of projects on Github. [Here](https://github.com/t-crest/patmos/blob/master/hardware/Makefile) is the one where I learned about `gnui`.